# Having multiple tabs in CMS Pagekit

Tags: pagekit

I tried to make my own extension in Pagekit. I'm making a chat extension:
[chat extension photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M70M2.png).

My problem is, I can't have a view per tab. Then, with all the demos around Pagekit, they only explain for a single and basic view.

My purpose is to have at the end a tab for join the chat (Client's page) and the other tab for creating the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you define in your index.php your routes and nodes, you'll have to bound to each of them a Controller which will give the view.